# Cannot add foreign key constraint, i can't find the mistake

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm just starting with this, but when i imported my file to sql to beguin filling all the information, it shows me the error on the above, i know it's given because it's not the same length or the same type, so i tried to look for it on the plane code or the work bench and i couldn't find it. Any ideas?
I'll really appreciate the help.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
    -- Tue Apr  3 18:56:56 2018
    -- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dhl_dummy
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- PresentaciÃ³n DHL para importar a Microsoft BI.

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dhl_dummy
--
-- PresentaciÃ³n DHL para importar a Microsoft BI.
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci ;
USE `dhl_dummy` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Proveedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Proveedor` (
  `Clave_Prov` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `CalleyNum` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  `Colonia` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Ciudad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CP` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Clave_Prov`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`PT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`PT` (
  `Num_art` INT NOT NULL,
  `stock_PT` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Prec_pub` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Num_art`, `stock_PT`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Empleado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Empleado` (
  `idEmpleado` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  `Apellidos` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `CalleyNum` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Colonia` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Ciudad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `CP` INT NOT NULL,
  `Salario` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` INT NULL,
  `id_depto` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEmpleado`, `id_depto`),
  INDEX `id_depto_idx` (`id_depto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_depto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_depto`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Departamento` (`idDepartamento`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Departamento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Departamento` (
  `idDepartamento` INT NOT NULL,
  `Area` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_emp` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDepartamento`, `id_emp`),
  INDEX `Id_empleado_idx` (`id_emp` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Id_empleado`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_emp`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Empleado` (`idEmpleado`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Proporciona`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Proporciona` (
  `Clave_Prov` INT NOT NULL,
  `Num_Art` INT NOT NULL,
  `Precio_proy` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Clave_Prov`, `Num_Art`),
  CONSTRAINT `Clav_prov`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Clave_Prov`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Proveedor` (`Clave_Prov`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo` (
  `idInsumo` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` DATE NOT NULL,
  `fecha_exp` DATE NOT NULL,
  `stock_insumo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInsumo`, `fecha_ingreso`, `fecha_exp`, `stock_insumo`),
  CONSTRAINT `Num_Art`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idInsumo`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Proporciona` (`Num_Art`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_insumo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_insumo` (
  `Num_pedido` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_Insumo` INT NOT NULL,
  `cant_actual` INT NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_pedido` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha_llegada` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Num_pedido`, `id_Insumo`, `cant_actual`),
  INDEX `stock_actual_f_Insum_idx` (`cant_actual` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idInsumo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Insumo`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo` (`idInsumo`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Num_art`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Insumo`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`PT` (`Num_art`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `stock_actual_f_Insum`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cant_actual`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo` (`stock_insumo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Inventario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Inventario` (
  `Ubicacion` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `Refrigeracion` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `id_f_art` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_f_insumo` INT NOT NULL,
  `stock` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ubicacion`, `id_f_art`, `id_f_insumo`),
  INDEX `id_f_art_idx` (`id_f_art` ASC),
  INDEX `id_f_insumo_idx` (`id_f_insumo` ASC),
  INDEX `stock_f_inv_insum_idx` (`stock` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_f_art`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_f_art`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`PT` (`Num_art`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `id_f_insumo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_f_insumo`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo` (`idInsumo`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `stock_f_inv_insum`
    FOREIGN KEY (`stock`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Insumo` (`stock_insumo`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `stock_f_inv_PT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`stock`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`PT` (`stock_PT`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_cliente` (
  `id_pedido` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente_pedido` INT NOT NULL,
  `art_pedido` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pedido` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `ETA` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pedido`, `cliente_pedido`, `fecha_pedido`, `ETA`),
  INDEX `cliente_pedido_f_idx` (`cliente_pedido` ASC),
  INDEX `art_ordenado_idx` (`art_pedido` ASC),
  INDEX `fecha_client_idx` (`fecha_pedido` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cliente_pedido_f`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_pedido`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `art_ordenado`
    FOREIGN KEY (`art_pedido`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`PT` (`Num_art`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fecha_client`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fecha_pedido`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Cliente` (`fecha_pedido`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dhl_dummy`.`Cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhl_dummy`.`Cliente` (
  `idCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Pedido_arts` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pedido` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ETA` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`, `fecha_pedido`, `fecha_ETA`),
  INDEX `art_faltante_f_idx` (`Pedido_arts` ASC),
  INDEX `ETA_producto_idx` (`fecha_ETA` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `art_faltante_f`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Pedido_arts`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_cliente` (`art_pedido`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ETA_producto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fecha_ETA`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Re_stock_cliente` (`ETA`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What is the error message?  Have you tried to run each statement individually to see which one is giving you the error?

Comment: Error 1215 (HY000), how do i run it one by one, so i can try it and figure ot on what line or statement it it.

Comment: Please clarify via editing your post, not via comments. Also this is a faq: 1. google the error message 2. google your problem. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Also code questions require a [mcve]. Which here would find the problem code & get rid of all the unneeded lines. Also your description is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your script, and found the table `Insumo` failed to be created.

Then I ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to get more detailed information on the cause of the foreign key failure:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2018-04-03 18:22:32 70000df33000 Error in foreign key constraint of table dhl_dummy/insumo:

    FOREIGN KEY (`idInsumo`)
    REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Proporciona` (`Num_Art`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

Read the last sentence.

When you create a foreign key, you must match all the columns of the primary key in the table you reference. If the referenced table has two columns in its primary key, your foreign key must have two columns.

In your case, you tried to make a foreign key on one column `idInsumo` referencing the second column of another table's primary key.

```
FOREIGN KEY (`idInsumo`)
REFERENCES `dhl_dummy`.`Proporciona` (`Num_Art`)
```

But the primary key of `Proporciona` is two columns:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Clave_Prov`, `Num_Art`),
```

You shouldn't create a foreign key that references *part* of that primary key.

I didn't test further, but I looked at the later table definitions and I see you have similar mistakes in several other tables. You're trying to make foreign keys from columns that don't match the whole primary key of the table they reference.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the record, when i got a error and i need to find it, so i run the command.
     SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.
So should i just use, 'clave_Prov', and the other one just a refference, right?.
Thank you very much for the help. A newbe here.

Comment: If the referenced primary key has two columns, the foreign key must also have two columns.

Comment: "You shouldn't create a foreign key that references part of that primary key"--whatever "shouldn't" means--might be true *in a certain context*, but you don't give it, and you don't give the actual relevant restrictions on declaring FKs. It's this sort of unclear (misre)presentation that is part of why people are confused in the first place. An SQL FK *can* reference part of an SQL PK, and what's wrong here is the referenced list is not declared as unique & not null (via PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL) and doesn't have the same length as the referencing list. (As I'm sure you know.)

Comment: @philipxy: In standard SQL, a foreign key *must* reference a primary key or unique key, and *must* reference the whole key. That's the only thing that makes sense. But InnoDB has a weird non-standard behavior, that an FK may reference a partial unique key, or may reference a non-unique key. This makes no sense, because it leads to odd cases where a child row references *multiple* rows in the parent table, and that leads to unanswered questions about how referential integrity works. So to avoid these odd cases, one *shouldn't* do that! Just define FK's as in standard SQL.

Comment: I am talking about defining FKs as in the SQL standard. An SQL FK must reference the whole of *some* SQL UNIQUE NOT NULL or PK. But it can nevertheless reference a proper subset of a SQL PK. SQL UNIQUE NOT NULL & PK are analogues of superkeys (unique keys) not of CKs. One can be declared on a proper subset or superset of another. (One can be SQL PK, but it's not necessarily a PK/CK analogue.) So an SQL FK can reference a proper subset (or superset) of an SQL PK. You can say that one "should" in the sense of good style only define SQL PKs on PK/CK analogues... only you didn't say that.

Comment: `The Columns in the foreign key must match the number of, and have a comparable data type with, the corresponding Columns in the referenced unique key.` — from "SQL-99 Complete, Really" by Peter Gulutzan and Trudy Pelzer.